# Does ScummVM actually support Plumbers Don't Wear Ties?

Tags: scummvm, plumbers-dont-wear-ties

On April 1, 2017, ScummVM announced that it was [adding support for the PC version of *Plumbers Don't Wear Ties*](http://www.scummvm.org/news/20170401/). I was quite sure that supporting the game was an April Fool's Day joke (since they also said that they were changing their name to PlumberVM).

However, there is [a GitHub pull request](https://github.com/scummvm/scummvm/pull/932) for adding support for *Plumbers Don't Wear Ties*, which at first glance it looks feasible for a game that simple. And PC Gamer on March 24th [confirmed the existence of a PC version](http://www.pcgamer.com/thought-lost-forever-one-of-the-worst-pc-games-ever-has-been-found/?utm_content=bufferbdb0d&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter&utm_campaign=buffer-pcgamertw). But I don't have a copy of the game to try it out.

So does ScummVM actually support *Plumbers Don't Wear Ties*?

Comment: I don't know about Scumm, but a PC version exists, in fact it was developed first. Wikipedia says: [The PC Version was actually developed before the 3DO version, but due to a limited number of copies being made, it faded into obscurity, it however was uploaded to archive.org and can be found here:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plumbers_Don%27t_Wear_Ties) (with a link to archive.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes, it does (or rather, it will)

As of April 2nd, [the announcement](http://www.scummvm.org/news/20170401/) that ScummVM was supporting *Plumbers Don't Wear Ties* has been updated to clarify that it will indeed be supporting the game.

> **Update:** If you thought it was an April Fool's Day joke, you have been trolled. The Pull Request on GitHub is genuine, and ScummVM will really support Plumbers Don't Wear Ties if it gets merged.

However, it *was* an April Fools Day joke that the project was being renamed to PlumberVM.